# How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?

Tags: lubuntu, dpkg

I received this error after trying to download the icedtea plugin. After trying

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got the same exact error:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to open files list file for package `linux-sound-base': No such device or address
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I've already tried looking for solutions, but each one seems to be unique to the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-sound-base.info`

Comment: cat: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-sound-base.info: No such file or directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try first:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available 
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available  
sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done'
```

Dangerous, if previous instruction does not solve the problem...

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*Last may cause huge traffic load.*

Comment: Tried that, but I still got the same error. Should I paste something from the terminal?

Comment: I did get an error "rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/apt/archives/partial’: Is a directory". Updated and upgraded but still received the same error

Comment: I got an error "ls: cannot access /var/cashe/apt/archives: No such file or directory" which kind of concerned me. I go back a bit to find that /var/cashe doesn't exist. I don't have anything terribly important saved on the hard drive, would it just be easier to reinstall lubuntu?

Comment: Please explain why have you suggested `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*`?

Comment: @heemayl @user1940477 `clean` actually does that.. But i was *not* right, you should not do that, as people on the net say. **SORRY**

Comment: Nothing seems to have worked. Any last suggestions?

Comment: just reboot your system and then execute apt-get -f install

Comment: Worked. Can you explain the answer or share a link so that I will get an overview of this.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but I got the same error. I fixed the problem with this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 1):

I've Tried this from a German link (attached):

Download and start [available.ksh](https://media-cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/10/04/7312538-available.ksh). Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

([Source](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/dpkg-fehler-bei-aktualisierung/))