# Cannot upgrade to Vivid

Tags: 15.04

I'm getting this, do you know of a workaround:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-desktop
Error in function: 

SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 102, in apport_excepthook
    pr.add_proc_info(extraenv=['PYTHONPATH', 'PYTHONHOME'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 525, in add_proc_info
    raise ValueError('%s does not exist' % self['ExecutablePath'])
ValueError: /usr/bin/python3.4 (deleted) does not exist

Original exception was:
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Could not install the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A 
recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a). 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on ubuntu-session; however:
  Package ubuntu-session is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on unity-control-center; however:
  Package unity-control-center is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on unity-settings-daemon; however:
  Package unity-settings-daemon is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-desktop

Upgrade complete 

The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade 
process.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this prevented me from logging in to X after the upgrade because obviously `ubuntu-desktop`'s dependencies like `compiz` were broken.

I fixed it by going to a plain text shell (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and then following [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1404783/comments/12) with a small tweak:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
# add this line:   APT::Default-Release "vivid"; 
sudo apt-get -t vivid install apt/vivid
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2)

> Try to follow this steps:
>
> Ive Tried this from a german link:
>
> Firstable: Downlad and start this file from the link below
>   available.ksh
>   https://media-cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/10/04/7312538-available.ksh
>
> Then
>
> ```
>    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>    sudo dpkg --clear-avail
> ```
>
> then again:
>
> ```
>         sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```
>
> The where i had the information.
>   https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/dpkg-fehler-bei-aktualisierung/

Hope it help

Comment: thanks, I was a bit afraid to run this huge script, seems way too long and  complex for fixing a small problem

Comment: but you fixed a problem, right? :-D

Comment: yeah, see my answer above