# I/O error uninstalling package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to remove a package from my system, and I'm getting an I/O error which I can't solve:

```
# apt-get remove gateone
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Los siguientes paquetes se ELIMINARÁN:
  gateone
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 1 para eliminar y 235 no actualizados.
Se liberarán 17,8 MB después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
dpkg: error fatal irrecuperable, abortando:
  leyendo la lista de ficheros para el paquete 'linux-headers-3.13.0-73': 
( reading file list for package ...)
Error de entrada/salida
( I/O error )
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Don't know what to do. I've tried this:
[How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2) but not the "dangerous" part, because I don't know what it would do.

The error keeps appearing. This is the information of my system:

```
linux mantra 3.13.0-73-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 4 15:31:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
```

Can somebody give an idea of what's happening and what to doç?

Comment: Looks like it may be time to replace your hard drive. check the `dmesg` output for errors from the storage (sata?) driver. Get ready to backup your stuff and replace the disk.

Comment: Damm, it's true. This seems to be the HD:

`[449068.193532] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20 SErr 0x0 action 0x0`
`[449068.196723] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000008`
`[449068.199944] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED`
`[449068.203073] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:28:a0:d6:5a/00:00:0e:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 4096 in`
`[449068.203073]          res 41/40:08:a3:d6:5a/00:00:0e:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>`
`[449068.209315] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }`