# Issue while updating my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

Kindly help with this issue. http://paste.ubuntu.com/18866967/

Details of the system
 Kernel Linux 3.19.0-33-generic (x86_64)
Compiled    #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015
C Library   Unknown
Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the system following this [How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2)

Issue resolved.. Thank you, @Cristiana Nicolae for editing the question.