# While Installing Odoo v9 in Ubuntu 16.04 'E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)'

Tags: software-installation, odoo

While installing Odoo v9 in Ubuntu 16.04 I got this error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

This is not the first time. I got the same error a while ago, I tried this solution: '[How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2)', but after that I needed to reinstall Ubuntu because of a `chown: setuid 0` error. After reinstalling when I again tried to install Odoo v9 it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo ufw allow ssh # for the purpose of remote management you need ssh and openssh-server
sudo ufw allow 8069/tcp  
sudo ufw enable  
echo "deb http://nightly.openerp.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install odoo
sudo service odoo start
```

You can now access Odoo from: yourIP:8069
Example: `http://162.243.69.108:8069`

**Update:** Odoo is actively maintained and gets updated regularly. The current latest stable version is Odoo 11. The link to get it is: `http://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/deb/` and when installing Odoo 11 the third line in the above code block should be changed accordingly.