# remove and re-install compizconfig-settings-manager with Unmet dependencies ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, compiz, dependencies

I started to have problems with the ConpizConfig Settings Manager, first in the form of the inability to update the package itself, now in continuous problems in installing other packages such as PySide.

I tired to re-install the ConpizConfig Settings Manager with several options (including the one reported here: [How can I remove and re-install Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity)) but none of them worked. The output that I obtained was:

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
[sudo] password for gigiux: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmetacity-private3a linux-headers-4.2.0-42 linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic
  session-shortcuts
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  compizconfig-settings-manager
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 296 not to upgrade.
131 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 4,594 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package compizconfig-settings-manager (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 compizconfig-settings-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

~$ sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
[sudo] password for gigiux: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'compiz-plugins-extra' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 compizconfig-settings-manager : Depends: python-compizconfig (>= 1:0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Recommends: compiz-plugins-default but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

~$ sudo apt-get purge compiz*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'compiz-plugins-main-dev' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-plugins-default' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-plugins' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-plugins-extra' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-plugins-main-default' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compizconfig-settings-manager' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-fusion-bcop' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-dev' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-gnome' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-mate' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compizconfig-backend-kconfig' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-core' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-plugins-main' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-core-abiversion-20151010' for glob 'compiz*'
Note, selecting 'compiz-core' instead of 'compiz-core-abiversion-20151010'
Package 'compiz-fusion-bcop' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compizconfig-backend-kconfig' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-core' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-gnome' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-plugins-default' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-plugins-main-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-mate' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-plugins' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-plugins-extra' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-plugins-main' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'compiz-plugins-main-default' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmetacity-private3a linux-headers-4.2.0-42 linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic
  session-shortcuts
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  compizconfig-settings-manager*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 296 not to upgrade.
131 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 4,594 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package compizconfig-settings-manager (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 compizconfig-settings-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What would be the issue and how could I resolve it?

Thanks

G

Comment: Did you try reinstalling without removing?

Comment: tried more or less anything i could find on the internet, but I cannot install or reinstall nothing since there is this unmet dependency for Manager.

Comment: I even tried to install a different GUI but I can't go through because I always obtain error code (1)

Comment: Does this work? http://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2 the first solution?

Comment: I am always getting errors for the compizconfig-settings-manager