# Need to install PHP 5.6

Tags: dpkg, php, lamp

I have tried these below commands to install PHP 5.6 while installing Lampp:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  sudo apt-get update 
  sudo apt-get install php5.6
  sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql 
  php5.6-xml
```

But I am getting this error:

```
php5.6 is already the newest version (5.6.32-
1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/usr/bin/dpkg: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (127)
```

I tried many below links:

- [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) [related to google chrome] | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688338/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-related-to-google-chrom)
- [Error while installing Apache; error is "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190184/error-while-installing-apache-error-is-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-a)
- [How can I fix E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591855/how-can-i-fix-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-2)
- [Debian dpkg broken after apt-get upgrade | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/debian-dpkg-broken-after-apt-get-upgrade)

But I am getting this error still, and now I am unable to use `apt-get -f install` or install any other software.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be that you want to install php5.6, yet your system says php5.6 is already installed.

Can you use apt-get or dpkg commands at all? It looks like there is a problem with libselinux.so.1 or with the cache.

Run [`ldconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) as root. That should fix possible errors with shared libraries that are not registered properly in the cache.

References:
[SE: Debian dpkg broken after apt-get upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/debian-dpkg-broken-after-apt-get-upgrade)
[SO: Resolve error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932825/resolve-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libselinux-so-1-in-ubuntu-14-04-lt)

Comment: Thanks Edmund, I have followed both links but it didn't work for me, I am unable to use   **apt-get install**        or install any other software cause of this error. please let me know if you have other way to resolve this error.

Comment: @Vivek Did ldconfig run and exit correctly? If not, you'd need a rescue cd, chroot into the environment and run ldconfig like that.
Reference: https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=294666 #36

Also: which version of Ubuntu are you using? What did you do prior to this error (as stated, you already had php5.6 installed, which doesn't come with most current Ubuntu versions, which makes me think you already had that ppa configured)?

Comment: I used **ldconfig** and it exit correctly but problem not resolved, I don't know how to chroot, I do created ** ondej/ppa** for PHP 5.6 that si why it is already showing ppa but I am unable to remove it due to same error. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your output actually saying you are already having PHP 5.6 latest version  on your system. However try the below.

Try `apt-get autoremove` then `apt-get remove <your package>` then install again your package `apt-get install <your package`>

Comment: For consideration I tried above commands but I got same error.